# Remove Text from .txt file using python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a text file that I need to append to be able to import into my database. There are some 4800 odd lines in the text file. The data is under. Can someone help me with a python script that will:

1. Read the file
2. Remove everything except lines with NDC,xxxxx-xxxx-xx
3. Write a new file with the data NDC,XXXXX-XXXX-XX

Notice that the NDC is some time in XXXX-XXXX-XX format and sometimes XXXXX-XXXX-XX format.

Here is some data:

```
NDC,0065-0795-50

5.25667
48320,2
NDC,0517-2650-25

0.0411

NDC,51079-190-20

0.1582

NDC,0603-5450-21

0.7924
```

Comment: Not really - SO is a Q&A format for voluntary assistance towards a problem that shows effort on your part... can we see what you've tried so far, otherwise this will just show as a "write me the code" question

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If a line has an `NDC,XXXXX-XXXX-XX`, do you want to write the entire line, or just that part of it? And can a line have two of them?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that what you're trying to do may be a better job for `grep`/`ack`, `awk`, `sed`, and/or other simple Unix filters than for Python.

Comment: @abarnert I think a key point may be understanding what `The data is under` is...

Comment: Sonds like homework? the data above

Comment: @JonClements: 5 seconds with Google tells me that National Drug Codes have exactly this format. But how does that answer any of my questions? I still don't know whether the OP wants every line that has an NDC in it or every NDC, or whether there can be multiple NDCs on the same line, or anything else.

Comment: @abarnert I think you have made a perfectly reasonable shot in the dark call on your answer - and that's what it is - "in the dark" - until the OP shines the the light upon us...

Comment: The above data is an export from one of our NDC database. I wanted to dump everything thats in the export except lines with NDC,XXXX-XXXX-XX or NDC,XXXXX-XXXX-XX to import into another database. The solution by #abarnert has helped me save some time. I am not a programmer by any means let alone Python programming. I am in the process of learning on "job." Thank you for looking into it everybody.

Comment: @Shaji: I suspect anyone who didn't already know (or guess via Google) what "NDC,XXXX-XXXX-XX" meant wouldn't be helped by knowing it was an export from an NDC database. For future reference, when you ask questions here, don't assume people know your local jargon; if it might be relevant to the problem, explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(inpath, 'r') as infile, open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'NDC,' in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

This makes some assumptions:

- There is never any random text with `'NDC,'` in it except for your values. If that's not true, you may want to write a smarter test, possibly using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).
- You want to write the entire line if there's an `'NDC,'`, not just that part of the line. If that's not true, it should be easy to adjust—especially if you've done the above (because then you'll just write, e.g., the `re` matches instead of the line).
- And so on…

Since your question was so vague, there's no alternative but making guesses like that, and likely at least one of them will be wrong.

But this shows you what the structure of the program looks like, and you should be able to fill in the gaps yourself. Try it, then come back and ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: Actually I retract my comment to yourself on this question - this meets the OPs requirements so +1 and hopefully the OP will have enough to be moving forward now

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. You saved me a couple hours of data entry! Below is the code per your help and its result.--with open('c:\NDCImportGarbageData.txt', 'r') as infile, open('c:\NDCImportCleanedData.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'NDC,' in line:
            outfile.write(line) -- Well I cant put a screenshot here, but you get the idea. Again thank you.